# Print the name of function has highest value

Tags: php, laravel, function

My 3 different function given me value as below: in `JSON`.

[image]

I want to **PRINT name of `function` which has highest value**. The Functions are;

```
public function firstHourTrades()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $data = DB::table('finaltrade')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as first_hour'))
        ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
        ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '>=', DB::raw('exchanges.start_time'))
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '<=', DB::raw("ADDTIME(exchanges.start_time, '1:00:00')"))
        ->get();

    return response()->json($data);
}

public function lastHourTrades()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $data = DB::table('finaltrade')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as last_hour'))
        ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
        ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '<=', DB::raw('exchanges.close_time'))
        ->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '>=', DB::raw("SUBTIME(exchanges.close_time, '01:00:00')"))
        ->get();
    return response()->json($data);
}

public function otherHoursTrades()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $data = DB::table('finaltrade')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as other_hours'))
        ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
        ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
        ->whereRaw('finaltrade.created_at NOT BETWEEN exchanges.start_time AND DATE_ADD(exchanges.start_time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)')
        ->whereRaw('finaltrade.created_at NOT BETWEEN exchanges.close_time AND DATE_SUB(exchanges.close_time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)')
        ->get();

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

**FROM THE ANSWER I HAVE CREATED:**

```
public function allCmp()
{

$func_names  = ['firstHourTrades()','lastHourTrades()','otherHoursTrades()'];

foreach($func_names as $name)
    $results[$name] = $name();

$max       = max($results);

DD($max);

}
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far to compare the 3 values?

Comment: I want to print name of function in JSON which has highest value. In the screenshot, you can check the value returned and other_hours has highest value. I want to print Other Hours function has highest value. @kerbholz

Comment: Right, so what have you tried so far to make that happen? It's only three functions, you can call them one by one. What is the problem you need help with?

Comment: I don't how to do, should i create 4rth function? @alexis

Comment: Create one common function and execute all queries inside that function and check and compare with all queries response to check which response contain height value after then return the function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function one()
{
    return 1;
}
function two()
{
    return 2;
}
function three()
{
    return 3;
}

$func_names = ['three','one','two'];
// Call each function and store result.
foreach($func_names as $name)
    $results[$name] = $name();

$max       = max($results);
$max_funcs = array_keys($results, $max);

var_dump($max_funcs);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "three"
}
```

You may need to decode your JSON at some point, something like:

```
function get_val_from_my_json($json) {
    return array_values(json_decode($json, true))[0];
}

print get_val_from_my_json('{"some_key":5}');
```

Output:

```
5
```

And run all the results through that function (assuming valid json).

```
$results = array_map('get_val_from_my_json', $results);
```

Comment: thanks so much. i am learning many things from you. @Progrock

Comment: error:Call to undefined function `firstHourTrades()`

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati, that's because in your example above it is a method call.  You'll need to instantiate an object first, and you could then call like so:  `$obj->$name()`

Comment: Should i create 4rth function? `
public function allCmp()
{

    $func_names  = ['firstHourTrades()','lastHourTrades()','otherHoursTrades()'];

    foreach($func_names as $name)
        $results[$name] = $name();

    $max       = max($results);

    DD($max);

}`

Comment: What you have there won't work with those function names.  It's down to you how you aggregate and organise your code.

Comment: Now I understand that i cannot call function to another function. From our conversation, I found that i have to create class and object but, I dont know how to create it. So I asked ref if you can. I am getting error :FatalThrowableError in TimeFrameStatisticsController.php line 72:
Call to undefined function `firstHourTrades()`

Comment: I have added what i done from your code my question,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172831/discussion-between-kinnari-prajapati-and-progrock).

Comment: If you have your new method in the same class as the other methods you can use $this->$name() to call.  You don't want those brackets in the name itself.

Comment: Yes all methods are in this class : `class TimeFrameStatisticsController extends Controller
{`